# \luatexluaescapestring{\unexpanded{ and % inside string problem

Tags: luatex

I am passing code listings from latex to lua function for processing and formatting. Using `"\luatexluaescapestring{\unexpanded{ code }}"`  as main method to pass arbitrary code listing as is to lua, as string.

This works very well, except for one case I found. When the code contains a string itself and the string contains `%`, it fails. The code listing is cut off at the `%` start.

Is there a way to tell Latex to pass the string as is and not look inside it?
I thought that `\unexpanded` will prevent this. Here is a MWE (this is just an example. In actual code, I am doing much more than just putting `verbatim` around the code), I am using listing package and more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
function foo(myStr)
tex.print("\\begin{verbatim}"..myStr.."\\end{verbatim}")
end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

\directlua{foo("\luatexluaescapestring{\unexpanded{%
x=10; plotTittle=sprintf("%a pi", 3);  y=20;
}}")}

\end{document}
```

lualatex gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

TL 2016.

The problem is not the string inside the string. As this works

```
\directlua{foo("\luatexluaescapestring{\unexpanded{%
x=10; plotTittle=sprintf("a pi", 3);  y=20;
}}")}
```

And gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is the `%` used in the code which is the problem.

Question is: What to do to prevent latex from looking at the content of the string in any way? All strings are source code listing, from different languages.

Comment: this is just the same question over and over again `%` is a comment character so it comments out the rest of the line, see thetable on page 2 of the luacode package manual, use `\@percentchar` for something that expands to a `%`

Comment: Since you have loaded the luacode package why are you not using its environments which are designed to avoid you worrying about catcodes with direct use of `\directlua` ????

Comment: But since you have found the luacode package the main reason for which is to address the issue in this question, it's not unreasonable to expect that you might have got to page 2 of the manual where it documents how to make a `%` in the various ways of accessing lua. for `\directlua`  it says `No easy way` and the whole point of the package is to provide access to lua such that it is easy to use `%`

Comment: The `luacode` package provides the macro `\luastring`. Writing `\luastring{...}` is a lot simpler, IMNSHO, than `"\luatexluaescapestring{...}"` is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If for some reason you don't want to use `luacode` after having loaded the package then you can do

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\makeatletter
\let\percent\@percentchar
\makeatother

\begin{luacode*}
function foo(myStr)
tex.print("\\begin{verbatim}"..myStr.."\\end{verbatim}")
end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

\directlua{foo("\luaescapestring{%
x=10; plotTittle=sprintf("\percent a pi", 3);  y=20;}%
")}

\end{document}
```

or to use the package features:

```
\begin{luacode*}
foo('x=10; plotTittle=sprintf("%a pi", 3);  y=20;}')
\end{luacode*}
```

Comment: Thanks you, but is there a way to do this without modifying the listing I am passing to lua? I need to pass listing as is to lua without modifying it. I have lots of code, and can't change it to do this.

Comment: @Nasser see update

Comment: Thanks, but as in chat, this does not work for me, due to having strings and multilines. I give up on lua and using it for what I want. Not working.

Comment: @Nasser Due to the way TeX works (with catcodes) and the way the TeX<->Lua interface is set up (no 'special' treatment of augments to `\directlua`), passing inline Lua to TeX is non-trivial, with `%`, end-of-line, `--` for Lua comments, _etc._ all tricky. As has been said _many_ times on this, the best approach is to code the Lua in a separate file and `\directlua{(require"<Lua code>")}`, with arguments passed from TeX to Lua as required `\def\foo#1{\directlua{my.func(#1)}}` and so on.

Comment: Also valid: `\directlua{foo('x=10; plotTittle=sprintf("\percent a pi", 3);  y=20;')}`. No real need to use the `"\luatexluaescapestring{...}"` wrapper.

Comment: @Mico true I used `'` in the `luacode*` version for similar reasons, although it does of course depend on knowing there are no literal `'` in the string being passed in.