# obtaining a substring with \directlua when original string contains %-character

Tags: luatex, directlua, percent-sign

I want to implement in LaTeX a sort of function with two parameters

- a String containing a percentage e.g. "3.20 %"
- an integer, e.g. 2000
  The result should be the product of both numbers (in this case 3.20)

I tried to achieve this with a \directlua command, but I didn`t get the trick to handle a string containing the special character "%".

I tried something like:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}


\begin{document}
% I produce the LaTeX document such that the arguments to the calculation get filled in
% directly into the xxx.tex file. Yes I could fill in the value without 

Input arguments are
\begin{itemize}
   \item percentage: 3.20 \%
   \item factor: 2000
\end{itemize}

The result is: \directlua{
        s=string.sub('3.20 \%', 1, -3) 
        tex.sprint( s / 100 * 2000)
    }.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\@percentchar`

Comment: See also: [luatex - problem with string.format, \directlua and tex.sprint - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436979/problem-with-string-format-directlua-and-tex-sprint/436981#436981) ■ [luatex - \luatexluaescapestring{\unexpanded{ and % inside string problem - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315857/luatexluaescapestring-unexpanded-and-inside-string-problem/315858#315858)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: *a String containing a percentage e.g. "3.20 %", an integer, e.g. 2000 The result should be the product of both numbers (in this case 3.20)*      3.20 - Really?  ;-)

Comment: Why struggling with bringing percent-characters into the argument of the `\directlua`-directive at all if the only purpose of bringing them in is giving `string.sub` the opportunity of removing them? Why not just `\directlua{tex.sprint( 3.20 / 100 * 2000)}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the primitive instruction `\luadirect`, you could use the macro `\luaexec`, which is provided by the [luacode](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/luacode) package, to get the job done. Put differently, once the `luacode` package is loaded, all you need to do is replace `\directlua{s=string.sub('3.20 \%', 1, -3)...` with `\luaexec{s=string.sub('3.20 \%', 1, -3)...`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for \luaexec macro

\begin{document}
Input arguments are
\begin{itemize}
   \item percentage: 3.20 \%
   \item factor: 2000
\end{itemize}

The result is: 
\luaexec{%
   s=string.sub('3.20 \%', 1, -3) 
   tex.sprint( s * 2000 / 100 )
}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right - I overlooked that with `\luaexec` the control symbol `\%` expands to a single  `%`-character and not to an escaped backslash trailed by a single  `%` as would be the case with `\luastringN`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\@percentchar`

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4]{article}

\makeatletter
\let\pc\@percentchar
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% I produce the LaTeX document such that the arguments to the calculation get filled in
% directly into the xxx.tex file. Yes I could fill in the value without 

Input arguments are
\begin{itemize}
   \item percentage: 3.20 \%
   \item factor: 2000
\end{itemize}

The result is: \directlua{s=string.sub('3.20 \pc', 1, -3) tex.sprint( s / 100 * 2000)}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: So in one place (itemize-environment) you need `\%` and in the other place (`\directlua`) you need `\pc`. I don't think this is what the questioner had in mind. If using two different things was acceptable, one could within `\directlua` just omit `\pc`/`\%` and do: `\directlua{s='3.20' tex.sprint( s / 100 * 2000)}` or `\directlua{tex.sprint( 3.20 / 100 * 2000)}` or whatever.

Comment: @UlrichDiez yes well the minimal example is a bit miinimal as clearly you can always optimise away substring of a constant string. I basically just tried to answer the question in the title: how to pass a `%` to Lua.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I'm tempted to use `\let\%\@percentchar` then use `\%` not so many places where the `\chardef` is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Expert users appear to prefer using `\directlua`. If you don't understand the concept of category codes in TeX well, I'd recommend using `luacode*` environment to avoid surprises.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
% I produce the LaTeX document such that the arguments to the calculation get filled in
% directly into the xxx.tex file. Yes I could fill in the value without 

Input arguments are
\begin{itemize}
   \item percentage: 3.20 \%
   \item factor: 2000
\end{itemize}

The result is:
\begin{luacode*}
s=string.sub('3.20 \\%', 1, -3)
tex.sprint( s / 100 * 2000)
\end{luacode*}
.
\end{document}
```

An alternative is

```
The result is: \luaexec{ s=string.sub('3.20 \\\%', 1, -3) tex.sprint( s / 100 * 2000) }.
```

Refer to the documentation of `luacode` package for details.

Another alternative is (not recommend because of surprises)

```
The result is: \directlua{ s=string.sub([[3.20 \%]], 1, -3) tex.sprint( s / 100 * 2000) }.
```

This will pass literally `[[3.20 \%]]` to Lua, which is valid Lua code because `\` inside `[[ ... ]]` are not processed.

Comment: @Mico No, the issue with OP's original code is that the correct Lua code is `'3.20 \\%'`, but because of catcode it's nontrivial to write exactly that. If you write `\%` you'll get `\%` verbatim because the macro is robust.

Comment: @user202729 main issue with luacode environments is they are environments so you can't easily use lua to affect any later code, that and I can never remember exactly what catcode and command setup is made by the various command and environment versions provided by the package

Answer (score 0):

The subject of your question is:

"obtaining a substring with `\directlua` when original string contains %-character"

`\directlua` on the TeX-side processes a piece of *⟨general text⟩*, i.e., a set of TeX-tokens.

`\directlua` is as if the tokens belonging to the *⟨general text⟩* are expanded by TeX and the set of tokens resulting from expansion are written to an external text file by TeX according to TeX's rules for writing tokens to external text files. Then that external text file is fed as input-file to a Lua interpreter. The Lua interpreter probably creates output and probably passes that output to TeX. The Lua interpreter can pass its output to TeX via routines like `tex.sprint` which insert characters into TeX's mouth. The Lua interpreter can also pass its output to TeX via routines like `token.put_next(token.create(...)...)` which append TeX-tokens to TeX's token stream which in turn begins in TeX's gullet.

Where is your focus when referring to "original string"? On the .tex-input-file? On the TeX-side? On the Lua-side?

To me it seems you are struggling with bringing percent-characters into the argument of the `\directlua`-directive while the only purpose of bringing them in is giving `string.sub` the opportunity of removing them.

Why not just `\directlua{tex.sprint( 3.20 / 100 * 2000)}`?  (The number `3.20` could as well be provided as a macro argument.)

In case you wish to know about methods for having the TeX-side pass characters which are special on the side of TeX as ordinary characters to the Lua-side, the following approach might be of interest to you:

Expl3 comes along with a fully expandable routine `\cs_to_str:N` which delivers the name of a control-sequence-token without leading escape character (usually backslash) by triggering two expansion-steps to `\cs_to_str:N`.
You can use this for obtaining a character token from the corresponding control symbol token. (With the following example `\cs_new_eq:NN` is used for giving the control word token `\GetCsName` the same meaning as  the control word token `\cs_to_str:N`.)
This way you can obtain special characters other than `%` as well as long as the corresponding control symbol token is not `\outer`.

This way ensuring that TeX supplies a sequence of characters that are properly understood by Lua and conform to Lua's syntax , e.g., escaping characters that in Lua need to be escaped, is still up to you.

You might be interested in combining usage of `\GetCsName`/`\cs_to_str:N` with `\luaescapestring` (=`\luatexluaescapestring` with less recent LaTeX releases) or `\luastring`/`\luastringN`/`\luastringO` from the package [luacode](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/luacode).

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_new_eq:NN \GetCsName \cs_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Let's use the Lua-backend for printing TeX's special characters:

\directlua{ 
  tex.sprint( 
     '\\verb*|%
                \GetCsName\}%
                \GetCsName\ %
                \GetCsName\$%
                \GetCsName\&%
                \GetCsName\#%
                \GetCsName\^%
                \GetCsName\_%
                \GetCsName\%%
                \GetCsName\~%
                \GetCsName\{%
                \GetCsName\\\GetCsName\"% Double quote must be escaped in Lua-string
                \GetCsName\\\GetCsName\'% Single quote must be escaped in Lua-string
                \GetCsName\\\GetCsName\\% backslash must be escaped in Lua-string
             |' 
  ) 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use expl3's `\char_generate:nn` for creating explicit character tokens of category 12(other):

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_new:Npn \CreateOtherChar #1 { \char_generate:nn {`#1} {12} } \ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Let's use the Lua-backend for printing TeX's special characters:

\directlua{ 
  tex.sprint( 
     '\\verb*|%
                \CreateOtherChar\}%
                \CreateOtherChar\ %
                \CreateOtherChar\$%
                \CreateOtherChar\&%
                \CreateOtherChar\#%
                \CreateOtherChar\^%
                \CreateOtherChar\_%
                \CreateOtherChar\%%
                \CreateOtherChar\~%
                \CreateOtherChar\{%
                \CreateOtherChar\\\CreateOtherChar\"% Double quote must be escaped in Lua-string
                \CreateOtherChar\\\CreateOtherChar\'% Single quote must be escaped in Lua-string
                \CreateOtherChar\\\CreateOtherChar\\% backslash must be escaped in Lua-string
             |' 
  ) 
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `\directlua`: `\luastring` does the magic.
Perhaps someone out there has a nice explanation why this works.
Every comment why this is working and if there are pros or cons for this approach are welcome.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{luacode} % for the use of \luastring

\begin{document}

Input arguments are
\begin{itemize}
    \item percentage: 3.20 \%
    \item factor: 2000
\end{itemize}

The result is: \directlua{
    s=\luastring{3.20 \%}
    s = string.sub(s, 1, -3)
    tex.sprint( s / 100 * 2000)}.
\end{document}
```